# Plotting multiple time series data ( long format ) into one plot?

Tags: r, plot, zoo

Suppose i have 3 time series data "a","b","c", each of them has 2 variables to be record in 7 days.

Here goes the sample code:

```
require(data.table)  
#Create data
DT<-data.table(type=c(rep("a",7),rep("b",7),rep("c",7)), time=1:7,V1=rnorm(7*3,10,5),V2=rnorm(7*3,100,20),key="type")
# plot.zoo
require(zoo)
plot(zoo(DT["a"])[,3:4])
```

[image]

I am able to plot one type a time (as above), but i want to plot all "a" "b" "c"... into that panel, where different colors represents different type of time series.

So what i am looking for is a plot which has TWO panels (for "V1" and "V2"), and within each panel, there are several lines ("a","b","c"...) with different colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for zoo classic graphics, zoo lattice graphics and zoo ggplot2 graphics:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(DT, split = 1, index = 2, FUN = identity)
Names <- read.table(text = names(z), sep = ".", col.names = c("screen", "col"))

plot(z, screen = Names$screen, col = Names$col) # also see note 3 below

library(lattice)
xyplot(z, screen = Names$screen, col = Names$col) # also see note 3 below


library(ggplot2) # also see note 4 below
m <- fortify(z, melt = TRUE)
m2 <- transform(m, screen = sub("\\..*", "", Series), col = sub(".*\\.", "", Series))
qplot(Index, Value, data = m2, col = col, geom = "line") + facet_wrap(~ screen)
```

*Notes*

1) If we just wanted separate panels it would just be `plot(z)`, `xyplot(z)` and `autoplot(z)`.

2) `names(z)` and `Names` are:

```
> names(z)
[1] "V1.a" "V2.a" "V1.b" "V2.b" "V1.c" "V2.c"
> Names
  screen col
1     V1   a
2     V2   a
3     V1   b
4     V2   b
5     V1   c
6     V2   c
```

3) We could have just hard coded it as this (in which case we would not need `Names`):

```
plot(z, screen = 1:2, col = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))

xyplot(z, screen = 1:2, col = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3))
```

4) Here is a ggplot2 alternative not involving `z`.  It converts `DT` to long form with data.table package and then performs the `qplot`:

```
long <- DT[, list(Series = names(.SD), Value = unlist(.SD)), by = list(type, time)]
qplot(time, Value, data = long, col = type, geom = "line") + facet_wrap(~ Series)
```

Comment: With `split` in `read.zoo` i am able to several columns, but i plot more panels (2*3) than i want (2).

Comment: Have modified to produce 2 panels in each case.

Comment: Thanks for such detail answer! I prefer the zoo classic graphics because i have a customized panel option(mainly deal with the x-axis). @G.Grothendieck 's answer works fine for the sample data i posted, yet  certain trivial work must be done before i apply them to my real data set. One thing is in my real data set there are other columns which i am not interested in plotting, and the `read.zoo` treated them as equal as `V1` and `V2`. so i will have to  remove them first. The other thing is I use `id` (large numeric like 85716 or 776444) rather than `type` (a,b,c), it might mean same color.

Comment: To only pass the first 4 columns of `DT`, say, use `z <- read.zoo(DT[, 1:4, with = FALSE], ...)` .  To ensure that the type is not interpreted as its numeric value make it a factor: `Names$col <- factor(Names$col)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `lattice` package for example , you can do this :

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(V1+V2~time,groups=type,data=DT,type='l')
```

[image]

You can also do it using `ggplot2`:

```
library(reshape2)
dt.m <- melt(DT,measure.vars=c('V1','V2'))

ggplot(dt.m) +
 geom_line(aes(x=time,y=value,group=type,color=type)) +
  facet_grid(~variable)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with `xyplot` or `ggplot`,but I think V1 and V2 better have their one y-axis,since they may have different range of values. with `layout=c(1,2)` i think i can make them share common x-axis. but still they have the same range of y-axis.

Comment: `scales = list(y = list(relation = "free"))` looks promising for xyplot

Comment: @JerseyGood yes. and for ggplot you do something like `facet_grid(cyl ~ variable, scales="free")`